# Echo only one row if there are multiply SQL entries in a table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

this is probably a PHP beginners question, I guess. Sorry for asking something that is probably very obvious to most. I am running a PHP request from a Linden Lab Second Life server to an external SQL database via an URL. I am sending the Player-Key in the URL. The http-response from the SQL database should then give the rank of the Player in the game.

I have written this code snippet and most of the time it serves its purpose:

```
 <?php

//You need to insert your specific data for "DB_HOSTNAME","DB_USERNAME","DB_PASSWORD","DB_DATABASE"

$con=mysqli_connect("DB_HOSTNAME","DB_USERNAME","DB_PASSWORD","DB_DATABASE");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//use the parameters in the http-link to set the $ variables and real escape them for security reasons (against injection)
$PlayerKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['PlayerKey']);

//Define which entry you chose from the database
$readthis = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT users_2015.Rank FROM users_2015 WHERE users_2015.PlayerKey = '$PlayerKey'");

//Fetch the information array
while($output = mysqli_fetch_array( $readthis )) {

// Print out the contents of each row into a table

    echo $output['Rank'];

}

//close connection to database
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

However there are some Players in Second Life that have bought access to the game several times. So they have several ranks. In this case there is not only one rank number displayed, but all the different returned strings are displayed as one large string. If someone has bought the game three times and he/she has the rank #199, #7 and #22, then the http-response given will be "199722".

Now my question: How can I change the code, so that only the last entry (in this case the #22) will be displayed? Alternatively: Is there also a method to only display the entry with the lowest value (=the best rank), in this case #7?

Thanks a lot for helping a PHP newbie out!    :)

Comment: `order by something DESC limit 1`, basically.

Comment: Take a look at the MySQL `MIN()` `MAX()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better approached as a SQL question:

```
SELECT users_2015.Rank FROM users_2015 WHERE users_2015.PlayerKey = '$PlayerKey' ORDER BY users_2015.Rank LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The proposal doesn't work for me unless I delete "ORDER BY users_2015.Rank". The following lline works for me: "SELECT users_2015.Rank FROM users_2015 WHERE users_2015.PlayerKey = '$PlayerKey' ORDER BY users_2015.Rank LIMIT 1"

Comment: I don't understand, that's the exact same query I provided. I just left off the surrounding quotes because I was focusing on the SQL, rather than the PHP.

Comment: I need to work on my precision. After looking one more time on my script I have to say: You are right, ignore my comment(s). Sorry.

Comment: no worries, I just wanted to know if I had given you bad info.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use while so it does not loop the ranks for you, instead:

```
$output = mysqli_fetch_array( $readthis );
echo $output[count($output)-1]['Rank'];
```